# Android gradle DexException : Library dex files are not supported in multi-dex mode

Tags: android, gradle, dex

My application reached the 64k limit recently.
I tried to create multiple dexes using --multidex option by adding :

```
exec java $javaOpts -jar "$jarpath" --multi-dex "$@"
```

in dx batch file.

While the build process completed successfully but upon running the application
it gave DexException : Library dex files are not supported in multi-dex mode

Now what does this mean ? I searched google for this but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--multi-dex` option to `dx` is incompatible with pre-dexing library projects. So if your app uses library projects, you need to [disable pre-dexing](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Improving-Build-Server-performance.) before you can use `--multi-dex`.

That said, I have no idea why this occurred to you at runtime. This clearly is a build time failure exposed by the `dx` tool. Maybe what happened to you is that parts of the app were rebuild when running from the IDE, triggering the build error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you explain more about the pre-dexed library projects. I have lot of library jars used in  my application so is there any difference between library jars and pre-dexed library projects ?
What exactly is a pre-dexed library project ?

Comment: The link from my answer actually explains it pretty well: Pre-dexing converts JVM to Dalvik bytecode for library jars. As library jars usually change much less often than the app's code, pre-dexed libraries can be re-used when re-building the app, and only the app's code needs to be dexed again. This way pre-dexed libraries help to speed up incremental builds. However, as also explained in the linked article, clean builds are slightly faster without pre-dexing as you have to only dex once in the end.